# Change column width of table with table-layout: fixed with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this markup

```
<table class="small" style="table-layout: fixed;" width="600px" cellspacing="0">
    <col style="100px" />
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="20px;"/>
    <col style="360px;" />
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:500px;" colspan="8">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:40px;" colspan="2">.</td>
      <td style="width:40px;" colspan="2">.</td>
      <td style="width:420px;" colspan="4">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:100px;" colspan="5">.</td>
      <td style="width:400px;" colspan="3" align="right">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;background:red;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;background:red;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:3600px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:200px;" colspan="6">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:200px;" colspan="6">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:240px;" colspan="8">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:240px;" colspan="8">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:240px;" colspan="8">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:240px;" colspan="8">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:240px;" colspan="8">.</td>
      <td style="width:360px;">.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I am trying to change the width of the first and last column. Setting the width of the first column to `100px` seems to work, however trying to set the width of the last column to `360px` doesn't?

What am I doing wrong here? Have tried a bunch of things. Setting the widths of every cell (above) and setting the widths of the cells I just want changed (row 1 cell 1 and row 4 cell 9).

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate: [table layout example](http://jsfiddle.net/HSVae/96/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **col** style definitions you are not specifying what property you are resizing. It should be:

```
<col style="width: 100px" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Silly oversight. Thanks for the 2nd pair of eyes!

Answer (score 1):

One of your rows says 3600!

```
<tr>
  <td style="width:100px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;background:red;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:20px;">.</td>
  <td style="width:3600px;">.</td>
</tr>
```

Best.(screen)resolution.ever.

Comment: But @Eraph should have you covered.

Comment: URGH! Terrible oversight! Thanks! p.s. sorry... I caught that typo in the JSFiddle but not in the above post! :)

Comment: Oh ho, I know that game ;) Anything to help!